# AWS CDK: Mapping of string to EC2 InstanceSize

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cdk

I am trying to make a build in CDK. It is supposed to spin up an EC2 instance and the size of it should be dependent of an input string. So string="micro" should create a MICRO instance and string="medium" should create a MEDIUM instance. I think I am supposed to use mappings so I have tried with different combinations of:

```
  const partitionMapping = new cdk.CfnMapping(this, 'PartitionMapping', {
    mapping: {
      'type': {"micro" : ec2.InstanceSize.MICRO, "medium" : ec2.InstanceSize.MEDIUM}},
      }
  });
```

but when I try to use the mapping for an ec2 instance with string set to "micro":

```
const inst = new ec2.Instance(this, 'persinst', {
    instanceType: ec2.InstanceType.of(ec2.InstanceClass.T2, partitionMapping.findInMap("type", string),
    machineImage: new ec2.AmazonLinuxImage({
        generation: ec2.AmazonLinuxGeneration.AMAZON_LINUX_2
    }),
    vpc,
    vpcSubnets: {
      subnets: [subnets_ids.subnets[0]]
    }
  });
```

I get the error:

```
lib/create-ec2-stack.ts:43:61 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'InstanceSize'.

43     instanceType: ec2.InstanceType.of(ec2.InstanceClass.T2, partitionMapping.findInMap("type", "micro")),
```

I was expecting it to pick up the value from the "type" mappings associated with "micro" which is an InstanceSize of EC2.

How can I make sure that the Instance Size of the EC2 instance is directly dependent on my input parameter "string"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is input parameter but not mapping. Either way `InstanceType` can be created in two ways

static method `InstanceType.of` or by passing type as string to constructor`new InstanceType()`

Assuming type is coming in as input parameter to cdk as this

```
const instanceSizeParm = new cdk.CfnParameter(this, "instance-size", {
  allowedValues: ["micro", "medium", "large"],
  type: "String",
});
```

We can use create InstanceType object by passing concatenated value as string to constructor.

```
  instanceType: new ec2.InstanceType(
    `${ec2.InstanceClass.T2}.${instanceSizeParm.valueAsString}`
  ),
```

Comment: Great! Glad i could help.

Comment: This does not work at least with the latest version of CDK (2.20.0 (build 738ef49)), I get: `Error: Malformed instance type identifier`.